# A question on a specific kind of prenex normal form

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, proof-theory, disjunctive-normal-form

We say that a first-order formula is in DNF if it can be obtained from a propositional formula in DNF by replacement of propositional variables with atomic predicate formulas. We say that $A$ is in PNF if $A=\textbf{Q}_1x_1\dots\textbf{Q}_nx_nA'$ where $\textbf{Q}_i$ are quantifiers and $A'$ is in DNF.

> Show that for any $A$ there exists a formula $B$ in PNF such that $A\equiv B$ and $B=\exists x_0\forall x_1\dots\exists x_{n-1}\forall x_nB'$ where $B'$ is in DNF.

Since we know that there exits $C=\textbf{Q}_1x_1\dots\textbf{Q}_nx_nC'$ in PNF such that $C\equiv A$ we can just put 'sham' quantifiers between any of $\textbf{Q}_ix_i$ and $\textbf{Q}_{i+1}x_{i+1}$ if $\textbf{Q}_i=\textbf{Q}_{i+1}$ (for instance, if $\textbf{Q}_i=\textbf{Q}_{i+1}=\exists$ we put $\forall y$ between them where $y$ does not occure in $C$). This way we get what we need but the result seems a bit hollow.

If we interpret the statement as "let $C=\textbf{Q}_1x_1\dots\textbf{Q}_nx_nC'$ be a PNF of $A$. There exists a formula $B$ in PNF such that $A\equiv B$ and $B=\exists x_0\forall x_1\dots\exists x_{n-1}\forall x_nB'$ where $B'$ is in DNF" then it looks implausible. For example, consder $A=\forall x\forall yR(x,y)$. This formula is in PNF. I see no way to build it's PNF looks like $\exists x\forall yA',\:A'$ is in DNF.

Maybe I miss something?

Comment: ... it seems like you answered the question yourself. Yes, put it in PNF, and add null quantifiers where needed. That may seem hollow, but it answers the question. And you're right, without adding such null quantifiers, it's not always going to work, so that's exactly what you need to do

Comment: @Bram28, thank you, I was not sure but now I am!